# How to decrease value of a variable with time

Tags: python

Here is the code for a game I a making, on lines 9-13 I am trying to make the hunger variable decrease every 180 seconds by 10, but it is not working.

```
import threading
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print("           Welcome to my game")
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")

health = 100
stamina = 100
hunger = 100
def hungerdecrease(h):
    global hunger
    threading.Timer(180,hungerdecrease).start()
    h -= 10

hungerdecrease(hunger)

while  health > 0 and stamina >0 and hunger >0:
    if  hunger <50:
        print("You are hungry.")
    if  stamina <10:
        print("You are feeling exhausted.")
    if  health <50:
        print("You are unhealthy.")
print("You are dead")
```

Comment: `hunger` is getting copied, so the function's modifying the copy only.

Comment: try adding a return to hungerdecrease and do `hunger=hungerdecrease(hunger)` . After your edit, shouldn't you modify hunger instead of h?

Comment: I am fairly new to python so forgive me if my questions sound stupid but I dont get what you mean by add a return to hungerdecrease

Answer (score 0):

- First, you don't need to pass the value since you just pass a copy. Just make the variable global.
- Then, your `while` loop needs some passive delay or you're looping with 100% active CPU.
- you have to protect against concurrent access of your `health` variable, using `thread.Lock`
- Another problem: the thread needs to stop rearming or the process doesn't exit. I stop rearming the thread when `health < 0`

A minimal complete & verifiable & working example, with timer set to 1:

```
import threading,time,sys

hunger = 100
stamina = 100
health = 100

lock = threading.Lock()

def hungerdecrease():
    global hunger
    if hunger > 0:
        # no rearm when dead
        threading.Timer(1,hungerdecrease).start()  # rearm timer
        lock.acquire()
        hunger -= 10
        lock.release()

threading.Timer(1,hungerdecrease).start()

lock.acquire()

while  health > 0 and stamina >0 and hunger >0:
    lock.release()
    time.sleep(0.5)  # so CPU isn't 100%
    if  hunger <50:
        print("You are hungry.")
    if  stamina <10:
        print("You are feeling exhausted.")
    if  health <50:
        print("You are unhealthy.")
    lock.acquire()
print("You are dead")
```